# Does a Stored Procedure calling a SQL Agent Job have to reside on the same server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-agent-job

I would like to create a stored procedure that calls a SQL Agent job, which will in turn call an SSIS package. The job and the SSIS package will reside on the same database server. However, I would prefer that the stored procedure resides on a different database server. The reason behind this is that we have an app that will be calling the sproc. I don't want to give it access to the database where the SQL Agent job and SSIS package reside.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In a different database in the same instance is very simple. Just use a doted name (db_name.schema_name.object_name).

In a different instance, you must create a linked server and use a doted name like :
instance_name.db_name.schema_name.object_name

Comment: i've had issues with this in the past using a linked server and an app (in my case ssrs). The authentication fails on the double hop through linked server. You authenticate fine into the first server, but going through linked server, you lose the original account info and are using a general account (that obviously doesn't have the authorization to run stuff on the linked server).